# DocuSign API - Custom Fields

Tags: vb.net, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign using their REST API in a Visual Studio Project (VB.NET).

I have successfully created a template in the interface, then using the API able to send this out to the users. This functions correctly.

We have set a First Name, Last Name, Email Address, Company and Sign here tags on the page. We can get FirstName, Last Name, EMail Address to populate using the XML doc.

```
  Dim requestBody As String = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=""http://www.docusign.com/restapi"">" & "<status>sent</status>" & "<emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request from Template</emailSubject>" & "<templateId>" & templateId & "</templateId>" & "<templateRoles>" & _
           "<templateRole>" & "<name>" & recipientName & "</name>" & "<email>" & recipientEmail & "</email>" & "<roleName>" & "User" & "</roleName>" & "</templateRole>"
```

However I cannot get the property of Company to be passed through? I am not sure where abouts this would be passed?

Next, how do I achieve the same solution but using the Custom Fields. I have created one - 
Label: Custom2
Type: Note
All other fields are default. 
But I am not sure how I can pre populate these values using the API?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify tab values with the API Request when creating an Envelope using a Template, you need to use the **compositeTemplates** structure within the API Request.

For example, the following request creates an envelope using the specified DocuSign Template that contains a single recipient (Role = ***User***) and 3 tabs for that recipient:  a *Company* tab having label = ***UserCompany***, a *Note* tab having label = ***Custom2***, and a *Text* tab having label = ***PhoneNumber***.  The request specifies the **value** for each tab (to prepopulate each field within the envelope).

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes

<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
   <accountId>ACCOUNT_ID_HERE</accountId>
   <status>sent</status>
   <compositeTemplates>
    <compositeTemplate>
        <serverTemplates>
            <serverTemplate>
                <sequence>1</sequence>
                <templateId>TEMPLATE_ID_HERE</templateId>
            </serverTemplate>
        </serverTemplates>
        <inlineTemplates>
            <inlineTemplate>
                <sequence>2</sequence>
                <recipients>
                    <signers>
                        <signer>
                             <email>johnsemail@outlook.com</email>
                             <name>John Doe</name>
                             <roleName>User</roleName>
                             <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                             <tabs>
                                <companyTabs>
                                    <company>
                                        <tabLabel>UserCompany</tabLabel>
                                        <value>ABC Widgets</value>
                                    </company>
                                </companyTabs>
                                <noteTabs>
                                    <note>
                                        <tabLabel>Custom2</tabLabel>
                                        <value>This is the note!</value>
                                    </note>
                                </noteTabs>                             
                                <textTabs>
                                    <text>
                                        <tabLabel>PhoneNumber</tabLabel>
                                        <value>111-222-3333</value>
                                    </text>
                                </textTabs>
                            </tabs>
                        </signer>
                  </signers>
               </recipients>
            </inlineTemplate>
        </inlineTemplates>
    </compositeTemplate>
  </compositeTemplates>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Since you're using XML format, you'll find this documentation useful --> https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help.  That page shows you the XML format for all requests (whereas the [DocuSign REST API Guide](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) contains mainly just JSON-formatted requests/responses).

Note:  Although the example reqeust above is consistent with DocuSign's documentation, for some reason the **Company** tab is not prepopulating successfully in my (limited) testing today.  If you experience the same issue, a work-around would be to use a "**Data Field**" tab (i.e., text tab) to collect/store "Company" within the DocuSign template (instead of using a "**Company**" tab), and then you can populate that field using a TextTab in the API request (just like the example above does for the PhoneNumber field).

Comment: Hi,
That's perfect thanks. Having the same issue with Company. That's a work around but my managers will want the tab for Company to work as they expect. Is there anything else you can suggest to resolve thi?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. This works as you say. Just wondering is there any chance we can get the Company Tab to work? My managers will want this to work as it should be before it gets rolled out.

Comment: You can contact DocuSign Support about the issue with the Company tab.  They'll probably try to point you back here to StackOverflow -- so you'll need to make it clear that you've discovered a bug with the API and are contacting them to report it. They'll want repro steps, so you can point them here to this post -- the code sample I've posted should suffice.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your help. Alex

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help.  Can you please mark this answer as "Accepted", so that others may benefit from this info in the future?  Thanks!